# When saving to array a smash stacking error crash the program

Tags: c

Sometimes when you save an object, a stack smashing detected error crashes the program. Its a basic program where you save an object, a car, and can output a specific car or the entire list of saved cars. A maximum of 10 cars. Sometimes when you save a car, after all information input, the program crash with a Stack Smashing Error

Main.c

```
#include "lib.h"
int main()
{
    fordon_type list[LANGD];
    int size = 0;
    lasin(list, &size);

    while (1) {

        meny();

        switch (get_choice()) {
        case '1':
            laggtill(list, &size);
            break;
        case '2':
            radera(list, &size);
            break;
        case '3':
            sortera(list, &size);
            break;
        case '4':
            printbil(list, &size);
            break;
        case '5':
            matauthela(list, &size);
            break;
        case '6':
            skrivin(list, &size);
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

lib.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define REGNR 8
#define STRSIZES 50
#define LANGD 10

void meny();
void printbil();
void matauthela();
void skrivin();
void sortera();
char get_choice();
void lasin();
void laggtill();
void radera();

struct owner {
    char name[STRSIZES];
    int age;
};

typedef struct fordon fordon_type;
typedef struct owner person;

struct fordon {
    char marke[STRSIZES];
    char nummerplat[REGNR];
    char type[STRSIZES];

    person owner;
};
FILE* fil;
```

lib.c

```
void printbil(fordon_type* list2, int* size)
{

    char position[STRSIZES];
    printf("Ange fordon att hämta: ");
    fgets(position, STRSIZES - 1, stdin);
    if ((atoi(position) - 1) > 0 || (atoi(position) - 1) < *size) {
        printf("\nName: %s", list2[atoi(position) - 1].owner.name);
        printf("\nAge: %d", list2[atoi(position) - 1].owner.age);
        printf("\ntype: %s", list2[atoi(position) - 1].type);
        printf("\nmarke: %s", list2[atoi(position) - 1].marke);
        printf("\nnummerplatt: %s", list2[atoi(position) - 1].nummerplat);
    }
    else {
        printf("Ange ett fordon mellan 1 och %d", *size);
        return;
    }
}

fordon_type skapafordonstyp(char* name, int age, char* type, char* marke, char* nummerplat, int* size)
{
    fordon_type f;
    char alderfordon[STRSIZES];

    printf("Skriv ditt namn: ");
    fgets(name, STRSIZES, stdin);
    strtok(name, "\n");
    printf("Skriv din ålder: ");
    fgets(alderfordon, STRSIZES - 1, stdin);
    strtok(alderfordon, "\n");
    strcpy(f.owner.name, name);
    age = atoi(alderfordon);
    printf("Skriv in typ av fordon: ");
    fgets(type, STRSIZES - 1, stdin);
    strtok(type, "\n");
    strcpy(f.type, type);
    printf("Skriv in märke på fordon: ");
    fgets(marke, STRSIZES - 1, stdin);
    strtok(marke, "\n");
    strcpy(f.marke, marke);
    printf("Ange nummerplåt: ");
    fgets(nummerplat, STRSIZES - 1, stdin);
    strtok(nummerplat, "\n");
    strcpy(f.nummerplat, nummerplat);
    f.owner.age = age;
    return f;
}

void laggtill(fordon_type* list2, int* size)
{
    int age = 0;
    char name, type, marke, nummerplat;
    if (*size == LANGD) {
        printf("Registret är fullt");
        return;
    }

    else {
        (*size)++;

        list2[(*size) - 1] = skapafordonstyp(&name, age, &type, &marke, &nummerplat, size);
    }
}

void meny()
{
    printf("\n1. Lägg till ett fordon\n");
    printf("2. Ta bort ett fordon\n");
    printf("3. Sortera efter bilmärke\n");
    printf("4. Skriv ut information om ett fordon\n");
    printf("5. Skriv ut hela registret\n");
    printf("6. Avsluta program\n");
}

void skrivin(fordon_type* list2, int* size)
{

    fil = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if (!fil) {
        printf("Filen kan ej öppnas");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (*size); i++) {
        fprintf(fil, "\n%s"
                     "\n%d"
                     "\n%s"
                     "\n%s"
                     "\n%s\n",
            list2[i].owner.name, list2[i].owner.age, list2[i].type, list2[i].marke, list2[i].nummerplat);
    }
    fclose(fil);
}

void lasin(fordon_type* list2, int* size)
{

    fil = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (!fil) {
        printf("Filen kan ej öppnas");
        return;
    }

    int lasin = 0;
    while (lasin != EOF) {
        lasin = fscanf(fil, "%s %d %s %s %s", list2[*size].owner.name, &list2[*size].owner.age, list2[*size].type, list2[*size].marke, list2[*size].nummerplat);
        if (lasin != EOF) {
            (*size)++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fil);
    return;
}

void radera(fordon_type* list2, int* size)
{
    int i, pos = 0;
    char position[STRSIZES];
    printf("Ange fordon att ta bort: ");
    fgets(position, STRSIZES - 1, stdin);
    pos = atoi(position);
    if (pos > 0 && pos <= *size) {

        for (i = pos - 1; i < *size - 1; i++) {

            list2[i] = list2[i + 1];
        }
        (*size)--;
    }
    else {
        printf("Välj ett fordon mellan 1 och %d", *size);
        return;
    }
}

void sortera(fordon_type* list2, int* size)
{
    int i, j;
    int k = (*size);
    fordon_type tmp;
    for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < k - i; j++) {
            if (strcasecmp(list2[j].marke, list2[j + 1].marke) >= 0) {
                tmp = list2[j + 1];
                list2[j + 1] = list2[j];
                list2[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

char get_choice()
{
    char text[10] = { 0 };
    while (!isdigit(text[0])) {
        fgets(text, 9, stdin);
    }
    return text[0];
}

void matauthela(fordon_type* list2, int* size)
{

    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < *size; j++) {
        printf("\nName: %s", list2[j].owner.name);
        printf("\nAge: %d", list2[j].owner.age);
        printf("\ntype : %s", list2[j].type);
        printf("\nmarke : %s", list2[j].marke);
        printf("\nnummerplat: %s\n", list2[j].nummerplat);
    }
    printf("%d", *size);
}
```

Comment: You probably need to use a debugger to figure out where you are corrupting the stack. likely you are going out of bounds of one or more of your arrays.

Comment: It's not a "smash stacking error" bu a "stack smashing error";-)

Comment: Hint: check if your array indexes are not out of range.